# Accessing outlets from function

Tags: ios, swift

I just started to learn Swift. I created a class that manages an REST API call and the method takes 3 parameters, data, successCallback and failCallback.

All good, I get the data, I parse the JSON, etc.

My problem is that I can't do anything related to IBOutlets inside the successCallback that is passed to the API method. I've tried self.textfield.text, textfield.text, nothing works. No error, nothing.

```
 func naturalSearch(data : String, callback:(NSDictionary) -> (), fail :(String) -> ()) {

    request(getLink("v2/natural"), data : data, callback : callback, fail : fail)
}
```

This is the API method.

```
service.naturalSearch(SearchTextfield.text, callback: processResponse, fail: responseFail)
```

This is how I call the method. Inside processResponse nothing related to outlets works. I have 3, 2 textfields and a tableview. I've tried hiding/changing label/etc but nothing works.

Thank you,
Mihai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're working in a callback function, which executes outside the UI thread. 
You should wrap your UI changing code with `dispatch_async`.

For example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.labelOutlet.text = "Text"
})
```

Comment: You're a life saver :D I was struggling with this for the past 3h. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can only modify UI Elements in the Main thread. To access it, use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { /* your Code */ }
```